# Disable webkit-spinner using JSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I have tried search both Google and Stackoverflow for an answer to this question but have been unable to find an answer.

Removing the webkit spinner from a date input when using CSS is relatively straight forward:

```
.modified::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.modified::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, I am unable able to achieve the same [result](https://codepen.io/alexandermckay/pen/WYMQBg?editors=1100) when styling in JSS (CSS in JS). I have tried the following:

```
'& input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
    webkitAppearance: 'none',
    '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
    display: 'none'
}
```

I would appreciate any insight you might have as to the correct syntax when using webkit and moz properties.

Thanks in advance.